# Using Webpack or Babel to consume node_modules via import statements on the Frontend

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, babeljs

So I'm trying to set up a Fontend JS project using `import` statements both for my custom components and for any `node_modules` I'd like to use. (I'm sure there are other ways I could do this, but this is the way I'm trying to do it for this project.)

I keep reading that I just need some combination of webpack and babel-loader, but I'm still having trouble.

When testing lodash, and using an import like this: `import lodash from 'lodash';` 
I get `Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/" ../etc`

Directly importing the full path gave a 404, for ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 9000,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        }
    }
};
```

I've tried not exluding node_modules

and my babel.config.js

```
const presets = [
    "@babel/preset-env"
];
const plugins = [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
];
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

I have much of this in a git repo [here](https://github.com/Seanmclem/Web-Component-Dev-Environment)

Comment: your `resolve` config is not pointing to your node_modules directory.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

Comment: @bobharley would that involve mostly just adding `modules: ['node_modules']` to resolve? So far after adding that there's no change

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path of node modules?
`path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')`

Comment: @bobharley ok I used `path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')` in my resolve > modules. Still same errors. I can see some output from webpack when I do `import lodash from 'lodash'` but the actual import doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and I found out your config is not creating an `index.html`.

And the `devServer.contentBase` is pointing to `./src` which is causing the error.
It should point to the output which is the `./dist` folder.

I updated your webpack config

```js
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src'),
  entry: './app.js',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['babel-loader']
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules'),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 9000,
    overlay: true,
  }
};
```

and on your `index.html`, remove the script tag pointing to `app.js`

Comment: that did it. I can now load my npm modules and my other js files and components together in the same way. Thanks!